Stokes’ theorem question for cylinder-like surface with two disjoint boundaries
Q: Consider $S=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=25,\; 0≤z≤4\}$ and the vector field $\vec F(x,y,z)=(y,-z,x)$. Use Stoke’s theorem to calculate $\iint_S(\nabla \times \vec F )\cdot \vec n \; dS$

$\vec n$ is the unit normal vector of $S$, pointing away from the origin.

Could someone please help me with this question? I've determined that the surface is supposed to look something like this , meaning that when I try to convert it into a line integral via Stoke's theorem, I will have to somehow deal with two disjoint boundary curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ somehow, whereby each curve points in the opposite direction from the right-hand-rule. This is my first time encountering a question where the boundary of the surface consists of curves that are not piecewise continuous.
The solution is apparently $-16\pi$

You can still just integrate over C_2 and C_1 separately, the only subtlety is taking the differing orientations into account

Following OP, only computation (easy) part remained.
Let $l_s: \vec r=\langle s\cos\theta, s\sin\theta,\sqrt{25-s^2}\rangle$, $0\leq \theta\leq2\pi$
on which
$\vec F=\langle s\sin\theta,\sqrt{25-s^2},s\cos\theta\rangle.$
Hence,
$$I_s=\int_{l_s}\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_0^{2\pi}(-s^2\sin^2\theta+s\sqrt{25-s^2}\sin\theta)\theta d\theta\\
=-s^2\pi$$
Since, $C_1=-l_3$ and $C_2=l_5$, by Stokes' theorem, the flux asked will be
$$-I_3+I_5=-(-9\pi^2)+(-25\pi^2)\\=-16\pi^2.$$

The direct method
$$F=\{y,-z,x\}$$
$$ G=\left(\nabla _{x,y,z} \ \times \  F \right) \ \cdot \ \frac{(x,y,z)}{r} = \frac{x-y-z}{r}$$
$$G /. \left(x \ \to \  r \ \sin (\theta )\  \cos (\phi ) \ , \ y \ \to \ r \  \sin (\theta ) \ \sin (\phi ) \ , \ z \  \to \ r \  \cos (\theta )\ \right) = \sin (\theta ) \ (\cos (\phi )\ - \ \sin (\phi )) \ - \ \cos (\theta )$$
With the surface element $$dS \ = \  r^2\ \sin(\theta) \ d\theta \ d\phi$$
$$\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}\  r^2 \  \sin (\theta ) \ \  \left(\int_0^{2 \pi } (\sin (\theta ) (\cos (\phi )-\sin (\phi ))-\cos (\theta )) \, d\phi \right) \, d\theta \ = \  \frac{16 \pi  r^2}{25} $$
The direct way: The vector field is the coefficient list of the 1-form
$$F=-r^2 \left(d\theta \ \left(\cos ^2(\theta ) \sin (\phi )+\sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ) (\sin (\theta )-\cos (\theta ) \sin (\phi ))\right)\ + \ d\phi \ \sin (\theta ) \left(\sin (\theta ) \sin ^2(\phi )+\cos (\theta ) \cos (\phi )\right)\right)$$
Its exterior derivative is
$$dF \ = \ r^2 \ d\theta \wedge  d\phi \ \ \left(-2 \cos ^2(\theta ) \cos (\phi )+\sin ^2(\theta ) (\sin (\phi )+\cos (\phi ))+\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta ) (2 \cos (2 \phi )-1)\right)$$
yielding
$$5^2 \int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)} \left(\int_0^{2 \pi } \left(-2 \cos ^2(\theta ) \cos (\phi )+\sin ^2(\theta ) (\sin (\phi )+\cos (\phi ))+\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta ) (2 \cos (2 \phi )-1)\right) \, d\phi \right) \, d\theta \ = \ 16 \pi$$
Here Stokes theorem would mean to do the $\theta$ integration first, not a good idea.
To stay at the abstract level, use the identity
$$\vec n \cdot \left( \nabla \times F\right) = \nabla \cdot \left(\vec n \times F\right)$$
and replace the area integral over the $\text {div}$ by the integrate outward flow over the boundaries.
But all these tricks of vector analysis amount to nothing more than to evaluate the 2-form area integral.
